# Infering missing ranges in a continuous scale

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-view

In my Oracle 11g database I have two tables for an order system. One table describes a discount, another describes a penalty, on orders within a given range of amounts.

Table `DISCOUNTS`:

```
| FROM_AMOUNT  | TO_AMOUNT | DISCOUNT
| 25           | 39        |  2%
| 40           | 49        |  5%
| 50           | infinty   | 10%
```

Table `PENALTIES`:

```
| FROM_AMOUNT  | TO_AMOUNT | PENALTY
| 0            |  9        | 10%
| 10           | 20        |  5%
```

These values are changed from time to time.

Since there is no good reason why these are separate tables, I have created a `DISCOUNTPENALTY` view, `union`ing these tables:

```
select discount.from_amount as from_amount, 
       discount.to_amount as to_amount, 
       discount.discount * -1 as change
union
select penalty.from_amount as from_amount, 
       penalty.to_amount as to_amount, 
       penalty.penalty as change
```

giving

```
| FROM_AMOUNT  | TO_AMOUNT | CHANGE
| 50           | infinity  | -10%
| 40           | 49        |  -5%
| 25           | 39        |  -2%
| 10           | 20        |   5%
|  0           |  9        |  10%
```

As you can see, the ranges are not overlapping, so for (almost) any given amount I can do a

```
select CHANGE from DISCOUNTPENALTY where :amount >= FROM_AMOUNT and :amount <= TO_AMOUNT
```

and get the correct discount/penalty. With the notable exception if `:amount` is in the range `21-24`.

In my data it is implied that an amount in the range `21-24` gives `0` discount/penalty, since that range is not listed in either `DISCOUNTS` or `PENALTIES` tables.

I would like to reflect that fact in my `DISCOUNTPENALTY` view, so that it will include a row for `21-24`:

```
| FROM_AMOUNT  | TO_AMOUNT | CHANGE
| 50           | infinity  | -10%
| 40           | 49        |  -5%
| 25           | 39        |  -2%
| 21           | 24        |   0% <-- Not from any table 
| 10           | 20        |   5%
|  5           |  9        |  10%
```

How do I go about having my view include this row? I suspect some analytical functions might be needed, but I'm not sure where to start.

Although a view is what I would prefer, it might not the most practical approach to this, so I'm open to other solutions. Note that I'm not able to alter the source tables in any way.

Comment: Are you sure that the intervals for discount and penalty will not overlap?

Comment: What about range 20-24?

Comment: @Incognito: The ranges will never overlap.

Comment: @EatAPeach: Ooops, that was a mistake. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the view.

This should do what you want (change the 2 literal to a variable, I tested it w/ a 2).

The first query grabs the discount if there's a discount. The second (connected by union) would grab a penalty if there's a penalty, but of an amount above the first row's from_amount, and the third (connected by union) would grab the penalty if there is one and it's below the first row's from_amount.

You can test it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/25188/0

```
with discounts as
( select 25 as from_amount, 39 as to_amount, .02 as discount from dual union all
  select 40 as from_amount, 49 as to_amount, .05 as discount from dual union all
  select 50 as from_amount, 99999 as to_amount, .10 as discount from dual  ) 
   , penalties as
( select 5 as from_amount, 9 as to_amount, .10 as penalty from dual union all
  select 10 as from_amount, 19 as to_amount, .05 as penalty from dual)
select discount as change
from discounts
where 2 between from_amount and to_amount
union all
select -penalty as change
from penalties
where 2 between from_amount and to_amount
union all
select -penalty as change
from penalties
where 2 < (select min(from_amount) from penalties)
and from_amount = (select min(from_amount) from penalties)
```

Regarding your last edit, the query below would show "0" for any amount for which there is neither a penalty nor a discount (the version of my query above would just show no rows for such a situation). You may prefer that it show zero, like this:

```
select discount as change
from discounts
where 22 between from_amount and to_amount
union all
select -penalty as change
from penalties
where 22 between from_amount and to_amount
union all
select -penalty as change
from penalties
where 22 < (select min(from_amount) from penalties)
and from_amount = (select min(from_amount) from penalties)
union all
select 0 as change
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from discounts where 22 between from_amount and to_amount)
  and not exists (select 1 from penalties where 22 between from_amount and to_amount)
  and 22 >= (select min(from_amount) from penalties)
```

If you change the SQL for that view to the below, you should get the range in between to show zero:

```
select discounts.from_amount as from_amount,
       discounts.to_amount as to_amount,
       discounts.discount * -1 as change
  from discounts
union
select penalties.from_amount as from_amount,
       penalties.to_amount   as to_amount,
       penalties.penalty     as change
  from penalties
union
select p.to_amount + 1, d.from_amount - 1, 0 as change
  from discounts d, penalties p
 where d.from_amount = (select min(from_amount) from discounts) and
 p.to_amount = (select max(to_amount) from penalties)
 order by from_amount desc
```

Comment: While this may work for that specific dataset, I should have been more clear that the actual ranges are subject to change. So hard-coding `25`, `39` etc into the query won't work in my case.

Comment: The with clause was just to hardcode your example data. Run the query starting at "select discount as change" against your actual database.

Comment: Also regarding your last edit, that missing range would result in no rows returned by the above query. So when you get no rows returned, it basically means that there is no discount or penalty. You could also add a union with another block to indicate that it would be zero.

Comment: I just added a query that will give you "0" if there is no range in either table (not a discount nor a penalty), using 22 as a literal to test (change each 22 to your variable).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Hope it's OK if I leave this question open a couple of days, to see if there are other solutions which does involve a view. A view of the complete scale is nice-to-have in my case, for a later task.

Comment: No problem, I added another union to your existing view that will show a row of 20 to 24 with zero (uses subqueries to get the min(from) from discounts and max(to) from penalties (then you just +/- 1 to each, to get your range between)